# What is the visa policy of Vietnam for Indian citizens?

Tags: indian-citizens, vietnam

I'm planning to travel to Vietnam but I have found no reliable information online. Websites suggest that Vietnam offers Visa on Arrival for Indian citizens but I'm not sure if it's actually a government website or not.

What is the official policy and where can I get some conclusive and reliable details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to arrange for your visa in advance. Note that, within the link, there is reference to visa exempt countries. At #19, India, exemption is made only for those who bear Diplomatic and Official passports, not for Ordinary passport holders.

[**Socialist Republic of Viet Nam Government Portal**](http://www.chinhphu.vn/portal/page/portal/English/visa-procedure)

> **VISA PROCEDURE**
>   Most visitors to Việt Nam need a visa to enter the country. Visas are exempted for the citizens of the countries, which have signed a bilateral or unilateral visa exemption* agreement with Việt Nam, tourist visa may be valid for 15 to 30 days.
>
> Tourist visa can only be obtained in Vietnamese embassies, consulates abroad. Otherwise, you can get a visa at the border gates if you are invitees of some Vietnamese competent organs or you are travelling on a package tour organized by Vietnamese travel companies. To apply for a visa, the requirements are as follows:
>
> - Entry permit form (which can vary from one Vietnamese embassies or consulate abroad to another) - There are two categories of this form: for foreigners and for Vietnamese overseas.
> - Two photos (4cmx6cm or 3cmx4cm)
> - Original passport
> - Visa fee.
>
> You should send your application and photos to a Vietnamese embassy or consulate abroad, which is most convenient to you. On your requirement, the reply will be returned by post (you must provide stamped envelopes with your name and address).
>
> It is easier to get your visa from a Vietnamese travel agency. The necessary information to the travel agency include:
>
> - Full name
> - Birthday and place of birth
> - Nationality
> - Job
> - Number of your passport
> - Entry and exit dates
> - Country you plan to receive your entry visa from the Vietnamese embassies or consulates
>
> **Vietnamese Embassy/Consulate India**
>   Address: No. 17 Kantilya Marg, Chanakyapari, New Dehli 110021
>   Tel: (91-11) 301859, 3017714
>   Fax: (91-11) 3017714
>   Email: sqdelhi@de3.vsnl.net.in

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of India arriving at Phu
>   Quoc (PQC) for a maximum stay of 30 days

So for visiting Phu Quoc, you don't need a visa.

For the rest of Vietnam, you can obtain an [e-visa](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/en_US/web/guest/khai-thi-thuc-dien-tu/cap-thi-thuc-dien-tu)

Answer (score -3):

Yes Vietnam provides visa on arrival. You can find complete details [here](http://www.chinhphu.vn/portal/page/portal/English/visa-procedure)

The procedure will be like this-

> Most visitors to Việt Nam need a visa to enter the country. Visas are exempted for the citizens of the countries, which have signed a bilateral or unilateral visa exemption agreement with Việt Nam, tourist visa may be valid for 15 to 30 days.
>
> Tourist visa can only be obtained in Vietnamese embassies, consulates abroad. Otherwise, you can get a visa at the border gates if you are invitees of some Vietnamese competent organs or you are travelling on a package tour organized by Vietnamese travel companies. To apply for a visa, the requirements are as follows:
>
> Entry permit form (which can vary from one Vietnamese embassies or consulate abroad to another) - There are two categories of this form: for foreigners and for Vietnamese overseas.
>
> Two photos (4cmx6cm or 3cmx4cm)
>
> Original passport
>
> Visa fee.
>
> You should send your application and photos to a Vietnamese embassy or consulate abroad, which is most convenient to you. On your requirement, the reply will be returned by post (you must provide stamped envelopes with your name and address).
> It is easier to get your visa from a Vietnamese travel agency. The nehossary information to the travel agency include:
>
> Full name
>
> Birthday and place of birth
>
> Nationality
>
> Job
>
> Number of your passport
>
> Entry and exit dates
>
> Country you plan to receive your entry visa from the Vietnamese embassies or consulates
>
> Vietnamese overseas are required to provide more information:
>
> Year and reason to leave Việt Nam
>
> Leave Việt Nam by means
>
> Full names and addresses of relations in Việt Nam

Comment: That doesn't look like a government site.

Comment: The site you've linked is not an official website, but an agency, and the question specifically asked for official policy and a reliable source. Please [edit] your post to improve your answer; otherwise, it may be assumed that you are simply posting to promote a site, and this answer may be deleted.

Comment: @Explorer we assume you're promoting your own site here? If so, please disclose your affiliation - it's fine to do so, but we need to know.

Comment: Also notice choster's comment about the requirements of the OP when editing your answer.